# Check if data in an array exist in a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array, containing some data and modelling a row. I want to check whether this "row " already exists in a sheet, whereas a particular column meets certain conditions.

For example, the "Birthday sheet" contains the following data

[image]

and I have the following array:

```
Dim arr(3)             'array modelling a row of the sheet

arr(0) = "Stellina"    'Name
arr(1) = 4             'Age
arr(2) = "F"           'Gender
arr(3) = #09/06/2012#  'Birthday
```

I would like to check if the data in the array are already present in sheet. But I want to analyse only the rows having birthday value between today and five days ago. This, just for avoiding the analysis of all the rows.

I am a bit concerned about comparing array and ranges. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you can figure out how to "Analyze rows having birthday value between today and five days ago" why not change that to get more exact and analyze only rows that share the same name, age, gender, and birthday as the array values? I think [`Range.Autofilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) would be very useful here.

Comment: Consider using a dictionary. The values can be iterated through with an array and it automatically does what you ask: doesn't allow for repeat values. You can find good information on excel VBA dictionaries [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Comment: @JNevill yes, but the proposed example is a huge simplification of the problem. there are lot of rows and columns and I am not sure would be so efficient to compare each cell of each row. I cannot be more exact on the condition, since it is dynamic in changes (every day I should lunch the vba).

Comment: @MattGaydon it is not a matter of repeated value: my goal is to check and do it in a subset of the excel sheet. but thanks for your suggestion, it surely will be useful in my future :)

Comment: So the question is which is more efficient. Using Excel's built in and very well tuned Autofilter feature, or hacking your own by sorting the data for birthdate and hitting a subset of the rows with a `For Each` loop? I'm going to go with Autofilter. IF the data is huge, then perhaps autofilter just for that subset of birthdates, copy to a new worksheet, and hit that with the autofilter to satisfy your column-by-column match for your array. Ultimately that's the expensive part so I would heavily rely on Excel's built-ins.

Comment: Also, a little off subject, I would hesitate to do any of this logic with large relational data and sensitive PII in excel. This is a job better suited for a database. Then you can just craft a nice parameterized sql statement from the array and hit the person/user/employee table. The script would be very small and it would execute extremely fast. Security would be tighter and you don't have to worry about data size and choose from 20 different vba solutions that have more cons than pros. You can even do the scripting VBA and bring the results back to excel if that's where you are comfortable

Comment: And.. perhaps as an interim solution you could use the ADODB library to query the the excel workbook you are in using the ACE driver. Then you can take advantage of query parameterization and a really quick search (let ACE do the work). Then if you ever migrate to a more robust, scalable, and secure solution like a SQL server, mysql server, postgres, or similar RDBMS product, you can just tweak the connection string in your code to point to the new location.

Comment: Thank you JNevill, I really appreciate very cultural and pro-active hints like yours, that starting from a question make the reader more aware about the context and how to avoid, rather then solve, future problems

Comment: @Bernheart - added another approach using the `Filter` method just for the sake of the art and to help other users, too. Maybe you can give it a try - would appreciate your backfeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying a multi-criteria worksheet function through vba.

```
debug.print cbool(application.countifs(range("a:a"), arr(0), range("b:b"), arr(1), range("c:c"), arr(2), range("d:d"), arr(3)))
```

Comment: it should check only if the required data are in the column, am I right?

Comment: It will only return true if one or more rows contain columns A:D with matching data.

Comment: Intersting, but I need an AND (not an OR) among the various check. Could we still use this command?

Comment: It is AND criteria.

Comment: So, basically, it is useful to check if an array is in the range. If it is true, there is.

Comment: Yes, it is there in at least one place. If you want to know specifically how many copies then examine the integer returned by countifs instead of casting it into a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach using `Filter` method**

Just to demonstrate another approach using the `Filter` method (applied on a redimmed data array) and as you mentioned in your OP:

> "But I want to analyse only the rows having birthday value between today and five days ago."

**Code example**

```
Sub chkDates()
  Dim arr(3)             'array modelling a row of the sheet
  arr(0) = "Lucy"        'Name
  arr(1) = 4             'Age
  arr(2) = "F"           'Gender
  arr(3) = #6/13/2018#   'Birthday
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Birthdays")   ' << change to your sheet name
  Dim n  As Long, i As Long, v, vx()

' [1] get lastrow
      n = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' [2] assign data to variant datafieldarray (2-dim, 1-based)
      v = ws.Range("A1:D" & n)
' [3] rearrange data in 1-dim (!) array to allow Filter method
      ReDim vx(1 To n)
      For i = 2 To n
          If v(i, 4) > (Now - 6) And v(i,4) <= Now Then     ' get only birthdays within last 5 days
              vx(i) = Join(Application.Index(v, i, 0), ",") ' join column data with colon delimiter
          End If
      Next i
' [4] get findings via Filter method
      Debug.Print "Filter string: " & Join(arr, ","), "Findings: " & UBound(Filter(vx, Join(arr, ","), True, vbTextCompare)) + 1
End Sub
```